# Resistor network with resistance of $\pi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, physics, integers

Given an infinite amount of identical resistors with resistance $R$, how to construct a resistor network with resistance $\pi R$? And how to minimize the amount of resistors used for a given error limit? Since total resistance is either the sum or sum of inverses of its components, I guess continued fraction is one way to approximate $\pi$, but would there be a more "intereresting" approach?

Comment: When connecting resistors in series or in parallel, then calculating resistance as either the sum or the inverse of the sum of the inverses will work. But for more complicated networks (example: an 2D square array), one must resort to [Kirchhoff's laws](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/circuits-topic/circuits-resistance/a/ee-kirchhoffs-laws) to determine the resistance between two points. And even with them, [it is not always easy](https://www.xkcd.com/356/).